# Heuristics vs meta-heuristics vs hyper-heuristics?

Tags: optimization, heuristics, search

[The wikipedia page on **meta**-heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic) states that they are "heuristics designed to find, generate, or select a heuristic".

[The wikipedia page on **hyper**-heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-heuristic) states that they are "heuristic search methods that seeks to automate [...] the process of selecting, combining, generating or adapting several simpler heuristics".

Moreover, it also states that "The fundamental difference between **metaheuristics** and **hyper-heuristics** is that most implementations of metaheuristics search within a search space of problem solutions, whereas hyper-heuristics always search within a search space of heuristics."

**This leaves me confused**: it seems like the hyper heuristic page is contradicting the meta-heuristic page. How can a meta-heuristic search for heuristics, if its search space is the problem space rather than the space of heuristics?

**What really is the difference between metaheuristics and hyperheuristics?**

Comment: Does [this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_major_difference_between_heuristic_hyper_heuristic_and_meta_heuristics_and_their_relationship_with_global_optimization_methods) answer your question?

Comment: @BruceAdams, the answers seem to primarily distinguish meta-heuristic from heuristic, but not clarify the difference betwen meta- and hyper- heuristics

Answer (score 1):

Defining meta-heuristics as "heuristics designed to find, generate, or select a heuristic" seems too broad. A meta-heuristic is commonly understood as an algorithmic template that defines how different low-level heuristic components (e.g. constructive procedures, local searches, solutions recombinations) interact in the search. After instantiating these components for a specific problem, you get a heuristic which searches in the solution space.

Gendreau, Potvin, [Handbook of Metaheuristics](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-1665-5) define them as

> solution methods that orchestrate an interaction between local improvement strategies and higher-level strategies to create a process capable of escaping from local optima and performing a robust search of a solution space

and chapter "Defining the term 'Metaheuristic'" of Zäpfl, Braune, Bögl, [Metaheuristic Search Concepts](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-11343-7) summarizes

> - A metaheuristic relies on a *high-level strategy* which builds upon a particular basic search principle
> - The high-level strategy is *problem-independent* and can be seen as an abstract framework
> - The high-level strategy has to properly realize a balance between the two forces *intensification* and *diversification*.

Thus, a short answer could be: **in a meta-heuristic the designer instantiates low-level heuristics; a hyper-heuristic automates the selection or generation of the low-level heuristics**.